# How would I remove an element from an array at a specific position in Python, using NumPy?

Tags: pythonxy

I need to simulate the flipping of a coin, with `heads = 0` and `tails = 1`. And each time a random number is generated between 1 and 0, heads or tails needs to be incremented and updated in the array.  Below is the code I have:

```
import numpy, random

flips = numpy.array([0,0])
coin = heads = tails = 0
for i in range(10):
  coin = random.randint(0,1)
  if coin == 0:
      heads += 1

(Now at this point, I want to update the second position of the array because that represents heads, how would I do that?  And the same for the first position, with tails).
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that do the trick ?

```
import numpy, random

flips = numpy.array([0,0])

for i in range(10):
    flips[random.randint(0,1)] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use pop

array = [1,2,3,4]

array.pop(1)

## now array is [1,3,4]

By default, pop without any arguments removes the last item

array = [1,2,3,4]
array.pop()

## now array is [1,2,3]

Comment: So array.pop() for an array is basically the equivalent the remove or delete function for a list?

Comment: the method remove for the list you pass an the value to be deleted, for the pop method you pass an the index.